# How can I reproduce this Stata comand in R? (confa)

Tags: r, statistics, stata

I need to reproduce this Stata command in R.

But I don't understand so much about `confa` and `stata`.

`confa` is a Confirmatory Factor Analysis  (CFA) package used in statistics.

> This is a multi-variate statistical technique used to assess the
> researcher’s theory, which suggests thenumber of (latent, or
> unobserved) factors and their relation to the observed variables, or
> indicators .CFA can be viewed as a subfield of structural equation  modeling
> (SEM) with latent variables when the latent variables
> are all assumed to be exogenous.

https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0900900301

Which package should I use? I saw something about `lavaan` and `cfa`, but I'm not sure which is better.

```
ssc install confa

confa (GROUP1: niveis_superv classe_bc) (GROUP2: idade_coop n_pac sudeste sul centro nordeste norte  atuacao_regional atuacao_estadual atuacao_nacional qtd_cooperados) (GROUP3: auditor contratar_auditoria_ind) (GROUP4: reunioes_ano estrutura_governanca membros comite) (GROUP5: cs_sobre_cooperados soma_pl_deposito ativocomp pl_sobre_ativos roa), from(smart)

estat fitindices

estat correlate

predict
```

Comment: Best to explain directly in statistical language what `confa` does, rather than hope that people will know and/or will try to find out what it does.

Comment: It's not my field, at all, but I suspect that `confa` (2009) is largely superseded by SEM support in official Stata.